# Compute how long it takes to complete the task when the machines A and B work together.

Tags: word-problem

> Suppose that there are two machines A and B that complete a task
>   within $4$ and $8$ hours respectively. The speed of A is reduced to
>   $1/3$ of its current speed, while the speed of B is increased by $3$
>   times. Compute how long it takes to complete the task when the
>   machines A and B work together.

My approach:

Machine A

$$\dfrac{1\space \text{task}}{4 \space \text{hours}}\times \dfrac{8}{3}\space \text{hours} = \dfrac{2}{3}\space \text{tasks}$$
Machine B

$$\dfrac{1\space \text{task}}{8 \space \text{hours}}\times 24\space \text{hours} = 3\space \text{tasks}$$

However, I'm not sure how that info is useful.

Comment: Of course, you have to assume that A and B can work independently on parts of the task.  Otherwise, for example if A and B are chainsaws and the task is cutting down a tree, then there's a time near when they would meet that you couldn't safely run both at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

It would take the new A 12 hours to finish the job, so it does 1/12 of the job each hour.  Also, it takes the new B 8/3 hours to do the job, so it does 3/8 of the job each hour.

Therefore, working together they do $1/12+3/8=11/24$ of the job each hour. So it takes them **24/11** hours to complete the job working together.